# Abstract method to be overridden with concrete type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class

Maybe this is a dumb question. But, I don't get the point what I am missing.

Given the following class-definition

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass
{
    public abstract void Create(AnotherAbstractClass param1);
}
```

Wheras `AnotherAbstractClass` is defined

```
public abstract class AnotherAbstractClass
{
}
```

with a concrete implementation

```
public class AnotherConcreteImplementation : AnotherAbstractClass
{
}
```

I want to be able to have the override of the `Create` method to use a concrete type:

```
public class ConcreteImplementation : AbstractBaseClass
{
    public override void Create(AnotherConcreteImplementation param1) <-- There is no suitable method for override
    {
        // param1 is an instance of the concrete implementation
    }

    public override void Create(AnotherAbstractClass param1) <-- this is working but I'll have to cast on each implementation
    {
        // param1 is an instance of the abstract class and needs a cast
    }
}
```

Is this simply not possible or is there some way I'm not aware of? Maybe using generics?

**Edit #1** (added more context)

I'm trying to achieve/enforce that in a concrete implementation there is only one parameter valid.
Think of it like it's a database-layer. The `Create` method will create a new entry in the database. As of each table has different values, the create-parameter also has. 
The casting inside smells (in my opinion) as of it can be called with any concrete implementation of `AnotherAbstractClass`.

```
public class AddressTable : AbstractBaseClass
{
    public override void Create(AnotherAbstractClass param1)
    {
        // cast to concrete instance
        var casted = (ConcreteAddressCreate)param1;
    }
}

public class CityTable : AbstractBaseClass
{
    public override void Create(AnotherAbstractClass param1)
    {
        // cast to concrete instance
        var casted = (ConcreteCityCreate)param1;
    }
}
```

Having an instance of `AddressTable` I can call

```
addressIntance.Create(new ConcreteAddressCreate()); // would be okay
```

on the other hand I can call it

```
addressIntance.Create(new ConcreteCityCreate()); // would be okay but will fail at runtime with InvalidCastException
```

**Edit #2** (additional info)

It should also be possible to extend the `AbstractBaseClass` class with more abstract methods later. 
So, for me it's more likely to have generic methods instead of an concrete class-implemenation with 200 generic parameters for each method to implement.

Comment: lol everyone answers you with a generic code snippet without any thought or real intention to help you, but just to scrap some points. Basically what you ask is possible, but it is a massive code smell and the real question is why do you think you need this? Could you give us more context, as I am confident that there is a better class design to achieve what you really need.

Comment: @dustinmoris I don't answer to just scrap some points, I have plenty of those and no use for them. I just meant to show OP a quick use of generics to solve this particular problem. I do agree that this looks like a code smell.

Comment: @dustinmoris this doesn't look like a code smell, and no one is "scrapping for points" (I cap quite easily on points anyway, there is a very high chance I literally get no points for answering this).

Comment: @dustinmoris see my updated question (trying to clarify my inteded goal)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The author asks how to cast the abstract type into a concrete type via overloads. To me this is a code smell, because the first question should really be why can he not work directly on the abstract type?

Comment: @KingKerosin So for each data type you need two classes to create a new record in the database? e.g.: AddressTable + ConcreteAddressCreate? Why can you not encapsulate all the "Address" operations in one implementation, so that the other type can be kept entirely generic?

Comment: @dustinmoris: It's not only to create. It will also have methods for complex update, delete or whatever operations on a single table. Update will have other classes than insert. But Insert and Update will have their respective base `BaseInsert` & `BaseUpdate`. What do you mean by one implementation?

Comment: this mey solve your issue  For all of your abstract classes you need to have atleast one  Concrete implementation in your codes. if so then you could use any of DI injector and tell you app to create Default object for you when you ask for abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

It violates the Liskov Substitution Principle so it makes perfect sense you can't do this. Namely, you can't just "have" covariance like this for free:

```
AbstractBaseClass bcl = new ConcreteImplementation();
bcl.Create(new DifferentImplementationWithoutSecondAbstract());
```

The contract AbstractBaseClass defines makes `Create` have to work with *any* implementation of `AbstractBaseClass` passed in - if you give a constraint on what can be passed in you've violated the contract it defines.

Like you assumed - you can use generics:

```
// notice the recursive definition, we require the generic parameter
// to be a generic parameter of itself - allowing AbstractBaseClass
// to not be aware of its subclasses like in the other answers.
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass<T> where T : AbstractBaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract void Create(T param1);
}

public class Concrete : AbstractBaseClass<Concrete>
{
    public override void Create(Concrete param1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what he asked for. You have only 1 abstract class in your example, but the original question has 2 abstract classes.

Comment: @dustinmoris I can add `public abstract class SecondAbstractClass<T> where T : SecondAbstractClass<T> { public abstract void Create(T param1); }` and then make `Concrete` extend that. It would add no substance to the answer - OP's problem isn't _actually_ caused because of the second abstract class. It's caused because of the constraint the contract in `AbstractBaseClass` forces on implementers.

Comment: T is supposed to derived from `AnotherAbstractClass`, not `AbstractBaseClass`.  It doesn't violate the Liskov Substitution Principle to do this.

Comment: @RobLyndon if you're talking about OP's question - it does because it violates "Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype." (or, even more directly: Contravariance of method arguments in the subtype) - by forcing the parameters to be of a subtype we violate the contract.

Comment: There does not seem to be an inheritance between `AbstractBaseClass` and the parameter `AnotherAbstractClass`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that using generics:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass<T>
    where T : AnotherAbstractClass
{
    public abstract void Create(T param1);
}

public class ConcreteImplementation : AbstractBaseClass<AnotherConcreteImplementation>
{
    public override void Create(AnotherConcreteImplementation param1)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This would force `AbstractBaseClass` to be aware of its subclass circularly.

Comment: why generic on class. you can make `Create` a generic. so this `public abstract void Create<T>(T param1) where T: AnotherAbstractClass;` and overridden like this `public override void Create<T>(T param1)
        {
            
        }`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - They aren't the same thing, making the method generic requires you handle and subclass of `AnotherAbstractClass`, putting it on the class requires you only handle one.

Comment: @Benjamin define "be aware". This code introduces no new dependencies that OP's example didn't have. Maybe the parameter from `Create()` is used in the class, so OP could need a `T _instance` field or call members defined in `AnotherAbstractClass`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary with `public override void Create<T>(T param1) { }` the issue stays that param1 is of the base-type, not the concrete one and I still need to cast

Answer (score 0):

Generics is indeed the way to do it.

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass<TDerivedClass> where TDerivedClass : AnotherAbstractClass
{
    public abstract void Create(TDerivedClass param1);
}
```

And then you can do:

```
public class ConcreteImplementation : AbstractBaseClass<AnotherConcreteImplementation>
{
    public override void Create(AnotherConcreteImplementation param1) // Works because TDerivedClass = AnotherConcreteImplementation 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is like CodeCaster's answer from a while ago - and suffers from the same problem of requiring the class to be aware of its subclass - this is not a necessary requirement - see my answer on how to prevent it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Can you elaborate how the class requires to be aware of its subclasses? It seems the class needs to be aware of the child classes of *another* abstract type

Comment: It needs to be aware of `AnotherAbstractClass`

Comment: And `AnotherAbstractClass` has no dependence on `AbstractBaseClass`, so where is the awareness of the subclass?

Comment: `AnotherBaseClass` needs to be aware of `AbstractBaseClass` because it extends it...

Comment: `public abstract class AnotherAbstractClass { }`